# Distribute a compiled JavaScript library using Bower and Grunt

Tags: git, github, gruntjs, bower, bower-install

I've released for the first time a JavaScript library using Bower (https://github.com/daveoncode/angular-ngkit), but since I'm not versioning compiled files (it sounds to me an huge bullshit despite I seen such approach for other repositories), user should build the library by himself using Grunt and I hate this... is there a way to launch a grunt build automatically for the final user? I saw a couple of js repositories on github like AngularJS and jQuery and they don't share generated files but only source ones, but by using `bower install (angular || jquery)` you get the compiled ones... how did they do this? Is it possible to use some kind of git hook or similar? By googling "bower hooks" I found this:

https://github.com/bower/bower/blob/master/HOOKS.md

But honestly I don't understand how it should work and neither AngularJS nor jQuery repositories seem to define commands which article is talking about :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery `bower.json` file points to `dist/jquery.js` which is the compiled distribution

```
{
"name": "jquery",
"version": "2.1.2-pre",
"main": "dist/jquery.js",
...
}
```

You will not find this directory or file in the master branch, however if you would switch to one of the tags (which are the actual releases) you will see it. For example in the [2.1.1 tag](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/2.1.1/dist).

AngularJS has a dedicated repository for the bower distribution - [angular/bower-angular](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular) - which differs from the sources [repository](https://github.com/angular/angular.js)

There is a popular [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170500/how-make-bower-build-the-package) in stackoverflow which deals with the issue of building on install in Bower and why it is an anti pattern.